# Alternative to search through a packed+unpacked array in systemverilog

Tags: multidimensional-array, verilog, system-verilog

I have this strange situation where i am currently doing this:

```
if (!this.randomize(delay) with {delay inside {strm};}) 
......
```

where

```
rand bit [2:0] delay;
bit [15:0] strm [bit [15:0]];
```

Now I want this delay to go in round robin from 0->....->7->0 and so on, but it should satisfy the condition that it should be present in strm. So I want something like

```
while (delay not in strm) begin
delay+=1;
end
```

Other than going though each and every index (2^16-1) is there any other way of finding if it exists in this packed+unpacked array? Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you have found a solution by now then please post it as self-answer. If answer posted helped you out to get it right then up-vote it or provide at least feedback on dwikle's question posted inside his answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not aware, you are declaring `strm` as an associative array (aka a hash), where the key and the data are both 16 bit values.

If you want `strm` to be a fixed-size 2^16 entry array of 16-bit values, the declaration would be:

`bit[15:0] strm [2**16];`

With associative arrays you can use `array.exists(key)` to determine if the key is in the array.  But it seems this may not be what you are trying to do.

With unpacked arrays, you can use the `inside` operator to test for set membership.  But my simulator (Incisive) does not like this usage outside of a randomization call.  So you may need to search for it yourself. However you don't have to iterate the entire array if you sort it first. And you can do that with `array.sort()`.

I would also point out that you are looking for a 3-bit value in some sort of array of 16-bit values.  This doesn't really make sense, so you may want to clarify your question.